# ImportError: No module named flaskext.sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use the [Sign in with SteamID](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/42/) snippet from the Flask site.  However, I get `ImportError: No module named flaskext.sqlalchemy` when I try to run it, and PyCharm says `Uresolved reference "flaskext"` and `Uresolved reference "OpenID"`.  I re-installed Flask-OpenID and Flask-SQLAlchemy to make sure they were there.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: As these snippets are no longer published, here is an archived copy for posterity: https://web.archive.org/web/20190207193459/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/42/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That snippet is really old. `flaskext` is no more (or at least very deprecated).  Refer to packages directly rather than through `flaskext` or `flask.ext`.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Flask-SQLAlchemy (and most other extensions) no longer register in the `flaskext` namespace, and `flask.ext` [was deprecated](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1135) then [removed in 1.0](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/changelog/#version-1-0). The only correct way to refer to extensions now is by directly importing them.

If you're still getting an import error, then you didn't install the package in the same Python environment you're running. Make sure you're using a [virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments).