# no SQLAlchemy module in Flask-SQL

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have tried both

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

and

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

inside flask/esk I only have a `__init__.py` and a `__init__.pyc`, and inside flask_sqlalchemy I only have `_compat.py`, `_coompat.pyc`, `__init__.py` and `__init__.pyc`. Should I copy the SQLAlchemy package in to one of these directories? I read here that ext is deprected so I'm unsure.

[stack-overflow deprected flask ext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837364/importerror-no-module-named-flaskext-sqlalchemy)

I'm getting these errors

```
ImportError: No module named flask_sqlalchemy
```

and

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy
```

I installed with pip

Comment: How did you install Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Comment: I used sudo pip, it was in a virtual env but i've also tried on my main machine.

Comment: Pip will install a library's dependencies, so SQLAlchemy should be there, too. Please update your answer with the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Yeah I know they should be there.

Answer (score 5):

Flask-SQLAlchemy doesn't come with Flask.  You need to install it.  You are correct, `flask.ext` is deprecated, but all it is is a "shortcut" for accessing other installed packages that are Flask extensions.  Since you haven't installed Flask-SQLAlchemy, you can't import it.

```
$ pip install flask-sqlalchemy
```

---

It is bad practice to manually install libraries to the system Python location (`sudo pip`).  Use a [virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing/#creating-virtual-environments).